# Tenserflow custom layer input doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I need to create custom layer for my model. Here is the code:

```
class Custom_layer_2(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, input_neurons_nmber, nn_neurons_number, connections_matrix, inputs_neurons):
        super(Custom_layer_2, self).__init__()
        self.cn = tf.dtypes.cast(tf.constant(connections_matrix),tf.float32)
        self.inputs_neurons = tf.dtypes.cast(tf.constant(inputs_neurons), tf.float32)
        self.nn_neurons_len = nn_neurons_number
        self.inpt_neurons_len = input_neurons_nmber
        self.w = self.add_weight(shape=([self.inpt_neurons_len+self.nn_neurons_len]), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True)
        self.b = self.add_weight(shape=([self.nn_neurons_len]), initializer="zeros", trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs_nn_neurons):
        self.input_matrix = tf.repeat([tf.concat([self.inputs_neurons, inputs_nn_neurons], 0)], repeats=self.nn_neurons_len, axis=0)
        return tf.concat([self.inputs_neurons, inputs_nn_neurons], 0)
```

It works perfectly, when I use as input predefined tensor of some shape:

```
nn_layer = Custom_layer_2(inputs_number, nn_number, conections_matrix, first_input_neurons)
input_tensor = [SOME TENSOR]
layer_1 = nn_layer(input_tensor)
```

Unfortunately, to create a model and to train it, I need to specify an input, so when instead of exact tensor I use input layer, code doesn't work for some reason:

```
nn_layer = Custom_layer_2(inputs_number, nn_number, conections_matrix, first_input_neurons)
inputs_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=(SOME SHAPE,))
layer_1 = nn_layer(inputs_layer)
```

This code throw ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2. As far as I understand, when I use  tf.keras.Input it create a tensor of shape (Nine,SOME SHAPE), whereas if I use exact tensor its shape is specified. What should I do in this situation, if a want to create a mode with custom layers?

Comment: The shape you pass to `tf.keras.Input` may not include the batch size (first dimension)

Comment: @danil-kutny I've tried to debug this, but am having trouble understanding what data this code expects.  Please add some values in the script for variables like `inputs_number`, `SOME SHAPE`, `first_inputneurons`, etc.  Something like `np.zeros(5,2)` or whatever shape is expected.  This will really help reproduce your error and bring clarity to what your customer layer is doing

Comment: inputs_number: 724; SOME SHAPE: 724; first_inputneurons: [0,1,...,722,723];